# QGIS difference of a layer with itself is not empty. Why?

Tags: qgis

I have a Multiline layer A with about 900 Features loaded (only a few of those are actually multi part geometries)  in QGIS 2.14.
I try to do Vector  -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Difference with Layer A as the input vector layer and Layer A as the difference layer, expecting to get as a result an empty layer.  But, the Output Shapefile has ~150 Features in it.  Topology Checker says, there are no invalid geometries, but there are about 90 pseudo nodes in the layer.  I started snooping around and found other line shapes that behave this way.  Have I fundamentally misunderstood what a difference is, or is there some specific geometry problem that causes difference to behave oddly?  The use case is silly, but I started with comparing an exported shape to its source, got weird results, and then tried to compare the source to itself as a sanity check.  Now I feel I might have lost sanity.  Help?

I get the same result in 2.8, so this is not a 2.14 bug.

Comment: Could you perhaps share your shapefile on a public server? I tested a multiline shapefile on QGIS 2.12.3-Lyon and I received an empty output.

Comment: https://github.com/HeatherHillers/funnythat

Comment: We are working in EPSG 31466.  These are legacy shapes produced in ArcView.  But saving them as new shapes or in a different coordinate System doesnt Change the result.  I also went through with the Topology Checker and removed all the pseudo nodes, so I dont get any geometry Errors anymore.  But it didnt have an effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure why this occurs when you use the *Difference* tool on the shapefile (perhaps multilines are not being processed correctly?) but to clean it up, I suggest using the **GRASS** function **v.clean** with the `break` tool which:

> break lines at each intersection

[image: v.clean]

I left the threshold at `0.1` and only output the `Cleaned` layer. There are more line features now from the original 877 to 1263:

[image: Cleaned layer]

Now when running the **Difference** tool on the cleaned layer, on itself, the output is empty as you would expect:

[image: Difference result]

Comment: Hey Thanks!  Although, that solution is going to cause some People some headaches.  I wish there was a nice hearty topology error so that I would know that my results are nonsense.  People doing a regular diff between data sets like this will not get real answers.

Comment: @MonsterMushroom - Most welcome! There is the **Geometry Checker** plugin which you can download from _Plugins > Download and Install Plugins_ which allows for both geometric and topographic error checking. This might be useful to use =)

Comment: Thats cool.  Although it seems to not allow topology checks on lines or multilines.